# How to install fonts to Microsoft chiseled Docker containers - .NET 8

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, .net-8.0

I'm working with the .NET8 Api project. It uses Imagemagick library to watermark the image with text. This application runs in a Docker linux container. It was throwing an error like:

> {ImageMagick.MagickTypeErrorException: UnableToReadFont `arial' @
> error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1654

Hence, I have added the code to install fonts in the Docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base

#install fonts
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb http://security.debian.org/ bookworm-security main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://security.debian.org/ bookworm-security main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i'.bak' 's/$/ contrib/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer fontconfig

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
```

This solved the issue on non-chiseled containers. But the production uses chiseled one with Ubuntu: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-jammy-chiseled.`

How to install fonts in this chiseled container?

Here is the full docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DemoAPI/DemoAPI.csproj", "DemoAPI/"]
COPY ["nuget.config", "nuget.config"]
RUN dotnet restore "DemoAPI/DemoAPI.csproj" --ignore-failed-sources
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DemoAPI"
RUN dotnet build "DemoAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DemoAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet:8.0-jammy-chiseled
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV SPYENV_Urls=http://+:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DemoAPI.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the font cache should be cleaned up. Here is the sample docker file for you.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-jammy-chiseled AS base


# apt update and install fonts
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends fontconfig ttf-mscorefonts-installer && \
    # clear cache
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    # update font cache
    fc-cache -f -v


WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
. . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "YourApplication.dll"]
```

Comment: Is this going to work for the fonts like Calibri as well?

Comment: Hi @DivyangDesai I haven't had time to test recently, the answer is just the usual way to make the font work.

Comment: Okay, I did try it, however, it gives same error with chiseled. Not sure where is the issue